# planar faces subdiv

Tags: mesh

how to control planar faces that arise from a subdivision? Is it possible to at least bend this planar to the outside without canceling the subdivision?
Various articles insist that planar faces should be avoided. It may bring artifacts later.
But how to control it in a subdivision?
If possible - share tutorials, faq, articles

thank you

[.blend-file](https://.blend%20file)
[image]

---

add topology. However, non-planar polygons are preserved when subdivided after topology has been added. How do you control non-planar polygons when subdivided?

[.blend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1s1.png)

[image]

Comment: you mean non-planar? You can't control the way the face will triangulate if this is your question, but what's the problem with it? If you want more control on the shape, add topology

Comment: added. still exist

Comment: Could you please share your file? The link doesn't work